# My Recyclerview position always give me "-1"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using retrofit to collect data and print my recyclerview. I just want to, when i click any one of the row, new activity opens. But i saw in logs, position values always "-1".I cant find any solution.Do you have any idea about it?
This log screenshot:[image]

This is my mainactivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),MyItemClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ApiClient.client?.create(ApiInterface::class.java)?.tumModelleriGetir()
            ?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<AracModel>> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<AracModel>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("hata", "" + t?.printStackTrace())
                }
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<AracModel>>,
                    response: Response<List<AracModel>>
                ) {
                    Log.e("başarılı", call?.request().url()?.toString())
                    var gelenData = response?.body()
                    var modellist= ArrayList(response.body()!!)
                    rv.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
                    rv.adapter=ModelAdapter(modellist,this@MainActivity)
                    //for (i in 0..response?.body()?.size!! - 1)
                      //  Log.e("başarılı", "" + response?.body()?.get(i)?.model.toString())
                } }) }

    override fun userItemClick(position: Int) {

        Log.e("pozisyon","pozisyon: "+position)
        when(position){

            3->{
                Toast.makeText(this,"deneme",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
class ModelAdapter(var modelliste: List<AracModel>, var context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ModelAdapter.AracModelViewHolder>() {
    private val itemClickListener = context as MyItemClickListener
    //var modellist = ArrayList(response.body()!!)

    var modellist = modelliste
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AracModelViewHolder {

        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var teksatirmodel = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tek_satir_model, parent, false)


        var opelViewHolder = AracModelViewHolder(teksatirmodel)
        teksatirmodel.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener.userItemClick(opelViewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }
        return AracModelViewHolder(teksatirmodel)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return modellist.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AracModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val oAnolusturulanSatir = modellist.get(position)
        holder.setData(oAnolusturulanSatir, position)
    }
    class AracModelViewHolder(viewGroup: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewGroup) {
        var teksatirliste = itemView as CardView
        var modeltitle = teksatirliste.tvListeBaslik

        fun setData(modelliste: AracModel, position: Int) {

            modeltitle.text = modelliste.model }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can setOnClickListener in onBindViewHolder of your adapter. 
You can get the item position there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this code as below

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AracModelViewHolder {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var teksatirmodel = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modal_layout, parent, false)

        var opelViewHolder = AracModelViewHolder(teksatirmodel)
        teksatirmodel.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener.userItemClick(opelViewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }
        return opelViewHolder
    }
```

return `opelViewHolder` instead `AracModelViewHolder(teksatirmodel)` new object

Answer (score 0):

`viewHolder.adapterPosition`is the position on the screen in pixels, not the position in the data list. And it is not always up to date. You should put a `var dataPosition` in your view holder implementation and set it in `onBindView`. Then use that in your click listener.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your call to the clickListener in the onBindViewHolder instead of onCreateViewHolder since items can be recycled and the position is given in parameters.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AracModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val oAnolusturulanSatir = modellist.get(position)
        holder.setData(oAnolusturulanSatir, position)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
               itemClickListener.userItemClick(position)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the following.

```
class ModelAdapter(var modelliste: List<AracModel>, var context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ModelAdapter.AracModelViewHolder>() {
    private val itemClickListener = context as MyItemClickListener
    //var modellist = ArrayList(response.body()!!)

    var modellist = modelliste
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AracModelViewHolder {

        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var teksatirmodel = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tek_satir_model, parent, false)

        return AracModelViewHolder(teksatirmodel)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return modellist.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AracModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val oAnolusturulanSatir = modellist.get(position)
        holder.setData(oAnolusturulanSatir, position)
        // her you can set click listener on your item view
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener.userItemClick(position)
        }
    }
    class AracModelViewHolder(viewGroup: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewGroup) {
        var teksatirliste = itemView as CardView
        var modeltitle = teksatirliste.tvListeBaslik

        fun setData(modelliste: AracModel, position: Int) {

            modeltitle.text = modelliste.model }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would instantiate a new listener every time a view is bound. Shouldn't be necessary.